# Mechanical Turk Get assignment results

Tags: r, mechanicalturk

I am trying to retrieve results from a batch of HITs I posted earlier using the `MTurkR` R package and writing those to a csv file. I personally completed several in the `MTurkR` sandbox but this error comes up when I use the `GetAssignments` function:

```
a <- GetAssignments(hit.type = git_hit_type$HITTypeId, return.all = T)
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "HITTypeId", value = "3FQBE1TSBOOM7YJ582RRD7RMUYDB6K") : replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

I'm not sure if this was caused by the way the HTML file submits HITS or if I am just using the function wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: This is my HTML code that may be part of the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-     public/externalHIT_v1.js'></script>
  <link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-public/bs30/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <form name='mturk_form' method='post' id='mturk_form' action='https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit'>
   <input type='hidden' value='' name='assignmentId' id='assignmentId' />
   <fieldset>
     <p>Issue #${id}</p>
     <p>Contents of the comment:</p>
     <p>${comment}</p>
     <p>Select all codes that apply to the comment:</p>
     <div class="checkbox">
     <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="VOT" />VOT: Voting</p>
    <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="REF" />REF: Justifying action based on external artifacts or standards</p>
    <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="DED" />DED: Developer Decisions</p>
    <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="DNN" />DNN: Assuming no discourse necessary/p>
    <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="RAS" />RAS: Rejection for administrative reasons</p>
    <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="EFT" />EFT: Enforcing tests</p>
    <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="MCD" />MCD: Making changes to documentation or tests</p>
    <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="CDO" />CDO: A devloper offering opinion</p>
    <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="IWO" />IWO: Inquiring into the work or options of others</p>
    <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="CTH" />CTH: Casual theorizing</p>
    <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="DPC" />DPC: Debating pros and cons of various solutions</p>
    <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="CVP" />CVP: Cross-validating problems </p>
    <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="SWC" />SWC: Suggesting different ways of changing a contribution</p>
    <p><input name="Answer" type="checkbox" value="REC" />REC: Referring to external conversation</p>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
   <p><input type='submit' id='submitButton' value='Submit' /></p>
  </form>
  <script language='Javascript'>turkSetAssignmentID();</script>
 </body>
```

So my question is, what could be causing this error with the GetAssignments function (could it be my html code?) and what can I do to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Could you please include the code that creates the objects in this statement?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I added the code that I needed to create the HITs. I am pretty sure that this is what you are asking for but let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: That's it, thanks Gordon. I may have to sign up an API key to help with this.

Comment: The code basically looks fine, so I suspect what is happening here is that there isn't any assignment data to return. Are you sure you're running all of the code in the sandbox OR all of the code on the live server? The easiest way to get an error like this is if you test the code in the sandbox and then accidentally use the sandbox HITTypeId to try to retrieve data from the live server, or vice versa.

Comment: I submitted a few of the HITs on the sandbox and was able to retrieve the HIT status with that the same git_hit_type$HITTypeId. My only other idea would that the .html file is not submitting the HITs properly. I will post the code of that above. Thanks!

Comment: I also use options(MTurkR.sandbox = TRUE) in my code

Comment: One thing to check: MTurkR logs requests and responses in a local tab-separated values file (`MTurkRlog.tsv`), probably in your working directory. Can you take a look at that and possibly paste in the XML response value (last column of the file) into your question?